# How can I use this Active Directory command for multiple groups?

Tags: cmd, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I need to apply WP RP members rights on multiple groups for 3 users. I tried below command ---

```
C:\>dsacls "CN=testgroup1,OU=Groups,DC=ram,DC=contosso,DC=com" /G domainname\user1:WPRP;Member domainname\user2:WPRP;Member
```

.... This is for single group. Please suggest ways to apply for multiple groups

Comment: hello soumya you can if you read help of dsacls you find out for groups or users you should use /R switch [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771151.aspx)

Comment: /r is for deletion..iam pretty sure about /g